# Is that possible for debian users to connect to network through systemd-networkd?

Tags: debian, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

**Systemd** offers the ability to manage the network by itself without additional tools such as **netctl** or **NetworkManager**. I am running  debian 8 and i need to configure my network using `systemd-networkd`

What are the requirement to manage the networks under debian jessie through `systemd-networkd`? And how to enable services and network?

Comment: There is an [extensive helpful wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd) in the ArchLinux wiki on the topic. It boils down to creating `.network` units in `/etc/systemd/network/` and related technologies. For a basic network, you just need systemd-networkd and systemd-resolved for DNS. Wireless gets more complicated but is also possible with wpa_supplicant. To enable/disable: systemctl.

Comment: Yes, it can, systemd is distro-independent (mostly). Of course you'd need different packages installed with `apt-get` and so on. But the configuration of systemd works the same in Archlinux, Debian, Fedora ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect to network through **systemd-networkd** you need to create some configuration files:

For wireless connections create **wireless.network** file with the following content:

`nano /etc/systemd/wireless.network`:

```
Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=20
```

For wired connections create **wired.network** file with the following content:

`nano /etc/systemd/network/wired.network` :

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
```

For wireless connections, create a configuration file for your access point by using:

```
sudo -i
echo "ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=sudo" > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
wpa_passphrase SSID password >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
```

exit

disable network-manager:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

Enable systemd-networkd :

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

Enable the `systemd-resolved` :

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

delete or rename `resolv.conf` then create a symlink to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Restart the srvice:

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

**Reboot**

Type the following command

```
root@root:~# sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

The output:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled)
Active: active (running) since lun. 2016-02-29 13:42:53 CET; 35min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
Main PID: 531 (systemd-network)
 Status: "Processing requests..."
 CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
         └─531 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

févr. 29 13:42:53 debian systemd-networkd[531]: wlan0           : gained carrier
févr. 29 13:42:53 debian systemd-networkd[531]: lo              : gained carrier
```