# systemctl status systemd-networkd showing up as dead

Tags: debian, networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

I am on Debian testing/strech. I looked at [Is that possible for debian users to connect to network through systemd-networkd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/is-that-possible-for-debian-users-to-connect-to-network-through-systemd-networkd)  and did the same things.

```
[$] cat /etc/systemd/network/wired.network

[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10%   


[$] sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved

[$] sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

[$] sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd systemd-resolved

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-networkd.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/systemd-networkd.socket → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.socket.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-resolved.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.

[$] sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet-desktop
```

and finally -

```
[$] sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd

● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
```

any idea what is wrong here ? Why systemd-networkd.service is being shown as dead ?

Update - rebooted the system and had to an -

```
$ sudo ifdown eth0
```

and then -

```
$ sudo ifup eth0
```

and then these two things show up beautifully -

```
[$] sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd

[sudo] password for shirish: 
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-11-07 20:44:52 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 764 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─764 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd


[$] sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved

● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─resolvconf.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-11-07 20:44:54 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
  Process: 962 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /run/resolvconf/enable-updates ] || echo "nameserver 127.0.0.53" | /sbin/resolvconf -a systemd-re
 Main PID: 896 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           └─896 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

I guess this worked out. The system is a dated workstation and hence has no wireless networking chip either on the motherboard or support on the chip itself hence didn't do anything about `wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: Run `systemctl start systemd-networkd` then verify the `status`

Comment: @GAD3R actually rebooted and at least it seems to run fine atm. Will know in a day or two.

Comment: `enable` creates the symlinks that ensure the service is run *the next time systemd starts* (usually on reboot), `start` starts the service *immediately*.  Use `systemctl enable --now` to do both.

Comment: That actually didn't work. See https://paste.debian.net/893326/ for more. Maybe some configuration file is missing, dunno. While I shouldn't need it, it doesn't seem to have any harm to have that as a service. `--now` switch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @jasonwryan see above.

Comment: If Debian has an older systemd without `--now`, you can just `enable && start`.

Comment: @jasonwryan  am running systemd 231-9 (on testing) but 232-2 has already come on sid/unstable.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the file: `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS= ajouter votre nom de domaine ici
#FallbackDNS= votre ip
#Domains= votre domaine
#LLMNR=yes
#DNSSEC=no
```

then type:

```
$ systemctl start  systemd-resolved.service 
$ systemctl status systemd-networkd systemd-resolved
```